# xampp does not run web pages for htpdocs

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I using xampp to run localhost but each time I try to run a web page it give me this error

`"This web page is not available"`

`"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"`

I try reinstalling xampp this work but once i shut down my laptop the same problem happen.when reinstalling a black command prompt appeared and when i run xampp it is still there if I close this prompt xampp will not run any web pages

I had to change Apache ports for 80 to 8080 and 443 to 4433

here is Apache error.log

```
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:24.613453 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:24.894728 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:24.957214 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:24.957214 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:24.957214 2015] [core:notice] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:24.957214 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 436
Apache server shutdown initiated...
sl:warn] [pid 436:tid 532] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:26.511729 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 436:tid 532] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:18:26.589879 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 436:tid 532] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:00.862040 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:00.987041 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:01.127643 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:01.174544 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:01.174544 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:01.174544 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:01.174544 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4556
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:02.514430 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4556:tid 456] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:02.717555 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4556:tid 456] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:02.788892 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4556:tid 456] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:18.656860 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:20.795957 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 436:tid 532] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Aug 10 07:22:20.827226 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8112:tid 560] AH00430: Parent: Child process 436 exited successfully.
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:46.225999 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00428: Parent: child process 4556 exited with status 1 -- Restarting.
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:46.585417 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:46.632250 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:46.632250 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:46.632250 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:46.632250 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5880:tid 532] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3856
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:47.802446 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3856:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:48.021182 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3856:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:48.083755 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3856:tid 516] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:53.326069 2015] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 3856:tid 516] AH02538: Child: Parent process exited abruptly. Child process is ending
[Mon Aug 10 07:23:55.357323 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3856:tid 516] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:24.319583 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5812:tid 524] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:24.569583 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5812:tid 524] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:24.632089 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 524] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:24.632089 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 524] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:24.632089 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5812:tid 524] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:24.632089 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5812:tid 524] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8172
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:25.960236 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8172:tid 444] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:26.163361 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8172:tid 444] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 10 07:25:26.225949 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8172:tid 444] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the xampp folder in your root computer folder. I.e. the C:// drive

Comment: The xampp folder is here C:\xampp\htdocs with is on the root drive

Comment: Hmm I have no clue what your problem is sorry. Hopefully someone else can help you out. May be something with your firewall idk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port number .if your port no is 8080 then link like http://localhost:8080/pd .